# How do you update two tables without joining in Node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

How do you update two MySQL tables with a single click of the retire button? I have created a table where you can edit based on the serial number of agent shown below. By clicking the retire button, it should change the AgentStatus to Retired and the policies under that agent to another agent. Is MySQL query correct or do I make two queries instead?

This is in my html for showing agent in agentavia
[image: Table with button]

This is the agentavia table to change status from active to retired
[image]

This is policy1 table where policyAgent will change to another agent name as they click the retired button.
[image]

Code for changing data in mysql

```
router.get("/retire/:id", function (req, res, next) {
  const AgentId = req.params.id;
  const sql = `SELECT * FROM agentavia WHERE id= ${AgentId}`;
  db.query(sql, function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render("modifyagent", { title: "Agent List", editData: data[0] });
  });
});

router.post("retire/:id", function (req, res, next) {
   const sql = `UPDATE * from agentavia and policy1 WHERE id= ? and agentStatus = 'Retired' and 
   policyAgent = 'Vani'` ;
          db.query(sql, function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;})
            alert("New agent shall take over your policies");
  });
});
```

Comment: Please provide sample of your table structure and sample data and which column you want to update.

Comment: So it is not possible to update two table in nodejs?

Comment: Is it possible to update the status of agentavia and due to update in status of agentavia, then update policy1 ?